# find equation of plane through point and having the same xz trace as plane

Tags: calculus

I need to find the equation of a plane through point $p(-4,1,6)$ and having the same trace in the $xz$-plane as the plane $x +4y -5z = 8$

I figured the $x$ and $z$ points remain the same, but I'm not sure how to find the correct $y$ value for this equation. The textbook lists the answer as $x + 42y - 5z = 8$, and I am unsure of where the $42$ is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the trace of the given plane in $xz$-plane ($y=0$) is

$$x-5z=8$$

thus the plane we are looking for has equation

$$x+ty-5z=8$$

by the condition on P we have

$$-4+t(1)-5(6)=8 \implies t=8+4+30=42$$

thus

$$x+42y-5z=8$$

Answer (score 0):

The trace in the $x$-$z$ plane is of course the solution set of the system of equations $$\begin{align} x+4y-5z-8 &= 0 \\ y &= 0, \end{align}$$ but there’s no need to find an explicit solution to this system. Every linear combination of these two equations also includes their intersection. Applying *Plücker’s mu*, the combination that also passes through the point $(-4,1,6)$ is $$(1)(x+4y-5z-8) - (-4+4\cdot1-5\cdot6-8)(y) = x+42y-5z-8 = 0.$$